# Can't Remember a Book about Binomial Sums and Hypergeometry

Tags: reference-request, binomial-coefficients, book-recommendation

Some time ago I had come across a website which had the online version of a book about techniques dealing with the solution of sums involving binomial coefficients, and something with the word 'hypergeometry' if I am not mistaken. I now remember neither the book nor the website. I remember that it had a blurb by Donald Knuth, who said that it had been very useful and fast for him (or some such thing).

Does anyone know the resource I am talking about, and can you give me a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean the book [A=B](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) by Petkovsek, Wilf and Zeilberger.

Read [Knuth's foreword](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/foreword.pdf).

Comment: This is exactly it. (Incidentally, I can't right-click on the first link because it's all MathJax, maybe some text would make it better.)

Comment: @shardulc, fixed.